# Display the lines of solar altitude in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I would like to have an option for drawing/displaying the solar altitude on the GIS map in the manner presented below:

[image]

grabbed directly from timeanddate.com.
You can see the terminator line and solar altitudes at 6, 12, and 18 degrees below the horizon. I would like to have these lines in the step of every degree between +90 and -90 if its possible.

Is there any plugin, which could do something like this?

The link to the thing I am after is here:

http://www.jgiesen.de/terminator/index1.html

Comment: Look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1742723/equation-of-a-circle-in-spherical-coordinates . Need to add angles to rotation axe.

Comment: These are just calculations, but I would like to have the plugin, tool, or something.